# Store row number of active cell in variable, switch to another sheet, put stored number in cell I3, end macro

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

Trying to write a simple macro in Google Sheets, simple stuff but I'm not familiar with the language; extremely frustrated. Please help.

I have two active worksheets in my workbook, Hotrods is a row delimited list,  CarDetail shows the details of the selected row... currently I input the row number of Hotrods in Cardetail to fill the form.

I'm trying to write a macro that stores the current row of Hotrods in a variable... switches to `CarDetail`, puts the stored value from Hotrods in `Cell (I,3)`, then terminates with the focus on `Cell (c,4)` of Cardetail. The VBA editor keeps throwing errors. I'm missing something obvious!

Please point me towards some good reading or give me some good tips! Thanks

Comment: VBA editor? Is this Excel or Google Sheets? There is no VBA in Google Sheets - there is Google Apps Script (an older JavaScript version)

Comment: Tehhowch... good point. t's Google Sheets. I'm finding out that Apps Script is a whole different animal than Excel's VBA.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working... probably not the cleanest code but it does the job!

```
function CarDetailForm() {                                      ;
  var fromSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName();
  // Should only run from the HotRods sheet 
  if (fromSheet = "HotRods") {                          ;
    var s       = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()             ;
    var ss      = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()        ;
    // Store HotRods active row number
    var rownum  = ss.getCurrentCell().getRow()           ;
    // Activate the CarDetail sheet
    s.setActiveSheet(s.getSheetByName('CarDetail'), true)  ;
    // activate cell I3 - or it won't work
    s.getRange('I3').activate()                          ;
    // set I3 to the row number carried from HotRods
    s.getCurrentCell().setValue(rownum)                  ;
    // exit macro with cursor in date field of CarDetail
    s.getRange('C4:I4').activate()                       ;
  }                                                      ;
}                                                        ;
```

Comment: `if (fromSheet = "HotRods")` is not what you wanted. **`=`** never compares things. Also note that you don't need to "activate" a `Range` to call `setValue` on it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my syntax error... I'm guessing that by using the = as opposed to the == I am setting the value of fromSheet to "HotRods" instead of doing the intended comparison. Also... Prior to posting the code to this forum I tried commenting out the .activate() line of code and it stopped working... I'll try it again.

Comment: Compare `s.getRange(...).setValue(1);` and `s.getRange(...).activate(); s.getCurrentCell().setValue(1);`

Comment: s.getCurrentCell().setValue() works just fine... and it appears to be significantly faster. Thanks for the pointer.